# Android Studio 2.0 does not start download

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I wish update Android Studio to 2.0. However, in the `Tools-> Check for Updates` section:

[image]

Selecting `Updates`, displays:

[image]

Selecting `Download` (in the top image) redirects to: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/, so that I can install a .zip with a seperate IDE, instead of simply downloading within Android Studio.

I do not wish to download and install a second separate IDE. In the past, this feature simply downloaded the new version and merged with the old.

What needs to be configured to get this to work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not related to programming, rather more, a networking issue where download fails.

Comment: I'm guessing the download doesn't fail, it's simply that it is not behaving as @Sauron expected.

Comment: @Graph, correct, but given it;s 23.0, this is necessary...

Comment: @Sauron sorry, but I don't understand. What is necessary?

Comment: @Graph, Im sorry, I meant to say, that given it's version 2.0, the full download may be necessary

Comment: @Sauron it is. In my answer below, I am giving some instructions that just helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior. Some updates cannot be directly patched and you need to download and replace Android Studio with the latest release. You should:

- Download the .zip file that you see in the page
- Unzip the downloaded file wherever you want
- Run the /bin/studio(64).exe file
- Import the settings
- Remove the old Android Studio directory
- Move the extracted dir to where the old Android Studio was installed
- Maybe optional: Rename it (maybe it was named android-studio) to "Android Studio"

Hope this helps, I have just done the same.